# En Django, ¿cuál es la diferencia entre un render() y un redirect()?

Tags: django, django-views

Dentro de django.shortcuts hay 2 funciones muy parecidas: render() y redirect(). Estoy tomando un curso, y realmente no logro entender cuál es la diferencia entre cada una.
Solo logro notar que redirect() no tiene un argumento request, pero no logro entender la diferencia a la perfección.

Comment: La función render, en otros lenguajes, es para cargar una vista. En cambio, la función redirect sirve para lo mismo, pero en su caso, lo que hace es redirigir al usuario a otra vista sin que haga falta hacer click en otro sitio. Por ejemplo, el usuario hacer login y tú en el método haces las comprobaciones necesarias y, luego, en vez de hacerle un render a la vista que deseas, le haces un redirect a la vista que deseas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estas dos funciones tienen objetivos diferentes.

Primero render() te permite combinar un template con un diccionario que le pases y como resultado te devuelve básicamente una pagina lista para mostrarse por el navegador.

Por ejemplo:

```
def home(request):
    return render(request, 'home.html', {
        'llave': 'Hola Mundo')
```

en home.html

```
<h1>{{llave}}</h1>
```

Esto le devolverá al navegador la pagina con el contexto ya insertado:

```
<h1>Hola Mundo</h1>
```

Para saber más ve: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/shortcuts/#render

Y redirect() te devuelve una respuesta con código 302 el cual indica un estado de redirección, por ejemplo, después de que envié un formulario donde registre un libro quiero que me redirija a la pagina con los detalles, para eso uso redirect() para indicarle a donde quiero que me lleve después. El parámetro puede ser una url, puede ser el nombre de alguno de tus path, puede ser un objeto, dependiendo de que es lo que le pases es como resolverá a donde llevarte.

Por ejemplo

```
def prueba(request):
    # Hacer algo aquí
    print('Hola mundo')
    # Llévame a google
    return redirect('https://example.com/')
```

Si quieres saber mas, ve: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect